# Is there a way for a function called within a with-statement to get the with object implicitly without passing it to the other function?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

Wondering if it's possible to pass a with-statement object to other functions implicitly.

Suppose the below code:

```
with get_something() as something:
    # do some things with it
    # then call another function for more things to happen
    do_other_things()
```

and in another module/class:

```
def do_other_things():
    # do other things
    print(something)
```

instead of passing the 'something' variable explicitly as in:

```
def do_other_things(something):
    # do other things
    print(something)

with get_something() as something:
    # do some things with it
    # then call another function for more things to happen
    do_other_things(something)
```

since we're in the with-statement context, is there a way, magical keyword, decorator, or else that would allow the function called within the 'with' to access its variables without passing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Just pass it in.